# How about assign function from service in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, service, controller

How about assign a function instead of create another new function in controller in AngularJS? why do?, why don't?

To do this:

```
//controller as example
function exampleCtrl(customService) {
    var example = this;
    example.doAny = customService.doAny;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
//controller as example
function exampleCtrl(customService) {
    var example = this;
    example.doAny = doAny;

    function doAny() {
        customService.doAny();
    }
}
```

I was doubtful becouse of this: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog Take a look of the DialogController in the JS tab.

Many Thanks.

Comment: There is no interest to create a function that will call another function

Comment: Why do you need to assign it to a scope property of the class

Comment: Yeah, I think that to, but I was doubtful becouse of this: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog
Take a look of the DialogController in the JS tab.
Cheers.